# Is there a specific token address?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Say I want to trigger a function within my smart contract upon receiving a specific token (e.g. BAT), is there any way I can verify that it's an actual BAT token?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not literally receive a token.

Inside the blockchain it will be just like adding your contract address to some mapping **somewhere** in the blockchain and you won't get any event or notification and you won't see the difference of having this token *by default*.

The only way I think you can implement it is to create your own database of tokens you are interested in and watch their events for any transfer transactions which includes your contract address. This can be made in `node.js` using `web3.js`. When the target event will be catched it can trigger some call to your contract.